# PHP MySQL query JOIN HELP

Tags: mysql, join

Hey everybody. So, I'm creating this kind of a social network script for a project of mine and i need it to display a news feed similar to facebooks feed, that is, to display your friends posts and your own posts...but with my technique it only displays friends post.

my query is the following:

```
SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                ajee_friends
            JOIN
                ajee_wall
            ON
                ajee_friends.fid = ajee_wall.uid
            WHERE 
                ajee_friends.uid = '$this->uid'
```

Comment: @Ikke he wants to display friends posts and his own posts, this only displays his friends posts.

Comment: `SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                ajee_friends
            JOIN
                ajee_wall
            ON
                ajee_friends.fid = ajee_wall.uid AND ajeee_firends.fid = this->uid
            WHERE 
                ajee_friends.uid = '$this->uid'` if got it right

Comment: i will try skowron-line-s way, the problem is, that it doesnt show my own posts.

Comment: With posts, do you mean entries in the `ajee_wall` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT *
    FROM ajee_wall w
    WHERE w.uid IN
        ( SELECT fid 
          FROM ajee_friends
          WHERE uid = $this->uid
        )
UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM ajee_wall w
    WHERE w.uid = $this->uid
```

Comment: @Asko: @Zoolway 's answer is equivalent (and shorter). Just check which one runs faster in your db (if that's an issue) or keep both saved somewhere.

Comment: I don't know, they both seem same fast to me. And great thanks to you all!

Answer (score 5):

If you want the wall of your friends and your own this can be done (in my opinion more readable as subselect):

```
SELECT *
  FROM ajee_wall w
 WHERE w.uid IN (SELECT fid FROM ajee_friends WHERE uid = $this->uid)
    OR w.uid = $this->uid
```

Comment: Of course you will want to limit the ammount and also add something like a date condition. But this should be the basic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Union all...
something like,

`SELECT * FROM ajee_friends UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ajee_wall`

It'll show all of your post and your friends'. You can make it show just a few lines with limit.